# How to add style to only that word where cursor is placed with document.getSelection()?

Tags: javascript, cursor, rich-text-editor, textselection, dom-selection

I want to apply the style only to that word where cursor is placed.

```
<p id="p">Hello</p>
<script>
  let range = new Range();
  range.setStart(p.firstChild, 2);
  range.setEnd(p.firstChild, 4);

  // toString of a range returns its content as text
  console.log(range); // ll
</script>
```

Comment: You can not "style" a range. You will need to split your paragraph content apart, put the selected text into its own element, such as a `span` - and then you can apply formatting to _that_.